# String variable in code differs to one in file

Tags: php, string

Could someone explain why I get two different outputs from a string variable.

The firs is loaded from a text file and exactly the same is loaded in code but I am getting two different outputs.

My test file called template.txt

```
{$photoName} {$photoHeading}
```

My php code

```
$photoName = "Name of the photo";
$photoHeading = "Headding of the photo";
$output = "";
                    
if(file_exists("../template/template.txt")){
    $templateFile = fopen("../template/template.txt", "r");
    $strTemplate = fread($templateFile, filesize("../template/template.txt"));

    $output .= $strTemplate . "\r\n${photoName} {$photoHeading}";
    echo $output;
```

The output I get is

```
{$photoName} {$photoHeading}
Name of the photo Headding of the photo
```

Comment: Variables aren't expanded when reading a string from a file, only in string literals (and only when the literal uses `"` delimiters).

Comment: BTW, `${photoName}` is deprecated, it should be `{$photoName}`

Comment: Is there a way I could get them expanded?

Comment: I have tried both ${photoName} and {$photoName} and get the same result.

Comment: Not automatically. It sounds like you want to use template software, there are many libraries. You can also use `preg_replace()` with a replacement function.

Comment: I know the result is the same. Deprecated doesn't mean it doesn't work, it means they plan on removing it in the future.

Comment: Yes I am trying to use a template, the problem with template software is I can not install anything on the hosting server.

Comment: See the linked question it shows how to write a function to do it.